# C# - Parsing a string to DateTime with just the hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm receiving the hours, minutes, and seconds as an integer user input.

Now, when I try and use DateTime.Parse and DateTime.TryParse AND Convert.ToDateTime, they all return the correct hours/minutes/seconds; however, it also returns the date (year, month, day and so on.)

```
        string a = this.hours.ToString() + ":" + this.minutes.ToString() + ":" + this.seconds.ToString();

        this.alarm = new DateTime();
        this.alarm = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "H:m:s", null);
```

Let's say that hours is 05, minutes is 21 and seconds is 50.
"a" would be 05:21:50. I would expect "alarm" to be 05:21:50. However, it actually is (may be):

```
11/23/10 05:21:50
```

Is there any way to make it work right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can see, it is working correctly. What are you expecting? The type is called `DateTime` because it stores a date and time.

Comment: Well, of course it returns a date and time, but I would expect that it parses it the way I tell it to. If that way is just the hours, minutes and seconds, then it shouldn't include the date as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A DateTime instance will always include some Date information.

If you're trying to represent just the time of day, you should use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) (with the TimeSpan representing the span since midnight...or the time of day. You'll also notice that the DateTime.TimeOfDay property does the same thing).

The code would be similar:

```
var timeOfDay = TimeSpan.ParseExact(a, @"h\:m\:s", null);
```

Answer (score 5):

The DateTime always holds time *and* date. If you want a class that only saves the time, you can create your own `struct` to handle that. But in the general case, there's no need to as you can simply ignore the date part of the DateTime struct, e.g.:

```
string a = "05:21:50";

DateTime alarm = new DateTime();
alarm = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "H:m:s", null);
Console.WriteLine(alarm.ToString("H:m:s"));
Console.WriteLine(alarm.Hour);
Console.WriteLine(alarm.Minute);
Console.WriteLine(alarm.Second);
```

Answer (score 2):

### [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, because DateTime, by design, represents a Date *and* a time.

There is no type in the .NET Framework designed to represent a time of day, but the closest would be TimeSpan. Consider wrapping it in your own TimeOfDay type, if Time-of-day semantics are important to you.

Answer (score 1):

New Answer:

Starting with .NET 6 there exists a built in [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly) struct which has a [constructor that takes hours, minutes and seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.-ctor#system-timeonly-ctor(system-int32-system-int32-system-int32))

```cs
var timeOfDay = new TimeOnly(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

---

Old answer:

No need to do any fancy parsing at all, [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-5.0) has a constructor that takes the hours, minutes and seconds as arguments. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) it is. So your code would just be:

```cs
var timeOfDay = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: A `TimeSpan` is **not** a `DateTime`! They are conceptiually different (duration vs. absolute time). Also, this question is 11 years old.

Comment: Yes! And this parse OPs `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` to a `TimeSpan`. And even 11 years ago, `TimeSpan` had this constructor [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-1.1#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the original .NET Framework 1.1 documentation for it. IMO the accepted answer has been wrong for OP's case for 11 years, there's no need to cobble together a string from 3 `int`s and the parse it as a `TimeSpan` if you can just straight up construct a `TimeSpan` from them

Answer (score 0):

As the other have mentioned here, a `DateTime`object will always contain a `Date`part, but the easiest is just to ignore it. Then, when printing it out, you can use the following syntax:

```
alarm.ToShortTimeString();
```