# How do I change the value that a ComboBox gets from a DateTime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently developing a Calendar application and I am storing a collection of DateTimes in a ComboBox. The current format of the string printed in the ComboBox drop down list is "Day/Month/Year Hours:Minutes" but I would like it to only display it in "Hours:Minutes" format, how would you change that?

EDIT:
I'd just like to clarify that the question was meant to be "How do I format the ComboBox" and not necessarily the DateTime.

Comment: Did you try anything ? Could you post some code if you have done anything ?

Comment: Well there's my problem, I don't really know how the ComboBox is retrieving the values from it's collection... I know that it calls DateTime.ToString() and I guess I could just make my own class that inherits from DateTime and overrides that function...

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260511/c-sharp-parsing-a-string-to-datetime-with-just-the-hoursminutesseconds)

Comment: Simple Friend  DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ComboBox has a [FormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.formatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) property which you can use to specify how a value is displayed.

This is particularly useful when using data binding.

In your case you could try setting FormatString property to "HH:mm".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DateTime.ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the DateTime to another Format use

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 04, 01, 15, 10, 0); // Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second
string formattedDateTime = dt.ToShortTimeString();
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format by using `String.Format(string,DateTime)` when adding the dates to the combobox. You can find a lot of examples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple

```
  DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the combobox, just use this convenience method in DateTime:

```
var exampleDate = System.DateTime.Now;
exampleDate.ToShortTimeString(); // will output hh:mm
```

If you instead need to override the `ToString()` method, as you mention in a comment, try:

```
exampleDate.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Note that there is a difference between `hh:mm` (hours up to 12) and `HH:mm` (hours up to 23). **See the [MSDN site for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on formats etc.**